# Require complex data sets for SQL practice

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I will be teaching few newbies to database systems in coming weeks as part of corporate training. This will include all major topics required to handle and develop on SQL systems.

Currently I am finding it difficult to find complex data sets useful for teaching. I need some data sets which has at least 4-6 fact tables and good amount of dimensions along with it. Will need them to work on complex joins and group by based queries in future. Plus, amount of data should also be good enough.

I know tableau resources have some good data, but that is very much linear or not enough for advanced SQL practice.

Domain is not necessary, data should be practice worthy. Can someone help me out here to where do I find it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seriously: create your own that contains data that will match the topics you teach

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Employees Sample Data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-introduction.html), I been taught with this database.

[image: Employees Structure]